# R: Cutting a year of dates into 2 month bins yields 7 bins instead of 6?

Tags: r, date, cut, bins

I am trying to use the cut() function in R to divide a year of dates into 6 two month bins. When I do, it makes 7 bins instead of 6, with the last bin being empty. I am using the following code:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2021-1-1"),as.Date("2021-12-31"),by="day")
months <- cut(dates,"month",labels=1:12)
table(months)
# months
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
# 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 
sextiles <- cut(dates,"2 months",labels=1:6)
# Error in cut.default(unclass(x), unclass(breaks), labels = labels, right = right,  : 
#   lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
sextiles <- cut(dates,"2 months",labels=1:7)
table(sextiles)
# sextiles
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
# 59 61 61 62 61 61  0
```

The code works fine when I divide the year into single month bins, but produces an error when I divide into 2 month bins, unless I account for 7 bins instead of 6 in the labels argument. If I start removing dates from the end of the year, the code eventually works with 6 bins after removing the last 3 days of the year:

```
dates_364 <- dates[-length(dates)]
sextiles <- cut(dates_364,"2 months",labels=1:6)
# Error in cut.default(unclass(x), unclass(breaks), labels = labels, right = right,  : 
#   lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
dates_363 <- dates_364[-length((dates_364))]
sextiles <- cut(dates_363,"2 months",labels=1:6)
# Error in cut.default(unclass(x), unclass(breaks), labels = labels, right = right,  : 
#   lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
dates_362 <- dates_363[-length((dates_363))]
sextiles <- cut(dates_362,"2 months",labels=1:6)
table(sextiles)
# sextiles
#  1  2  3  4  5  6 
# 59 61 61 62 61 58
```

This seems like a bug in the function. Can anyone shed any light on something I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to insight provided by @r2evans, I found the answer to my question.

There is a bug in the code for the cut.Date function. Lines 31 through 41 handle the case where breaks are in months:

```
if (valid == 3L) {
  start$mday <- 1L
  start$isdst <- -1L
  end <- as.POSIXlt(max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
  step <- if (length(by2) == 2L) 
    as.integer(by2[1L])
  else 1L
  end <- as.POSIXlt(end + (31 * step * 86400))
  end$mday <- 1L
  end$isdst <- -1L
  breaks <- as.Date(seq(start, end, breaks))
```

Line 38, `end <- as.POSIXlt(end + (31 * step * 86400))` adjusts the end ahead by 31 days times the step, or number of months in each bin. Because not all months have 31 days, there are instances where the end gets pushed back far enough to create a superfluous bin. This can easily be corrected with a few lines of code, as we see in the case when the breaks are in quarters. See lines 57 through 75:

```
else if (valid == 5L) {
  qtr <- rep(c(0L, 3L, 6L, 9L), each = 3L)
  start$mon <- qtr[start$mon + 1L]
  start$mday <- 1L
  start$isdst <- -1L
  maxx <- max(x, na.rm = TRUE)           # Note this line
  end <- as.POSIXlt(maxx)                # Note this line
  step <- if (length(by2) == 2L) 
    as.integer(by2[1L])
  else 1L
  end <- as.POSIXlt(end + (93 * step * 86400))
  end$mon <- qtr[end$mon + 1L]
  end$mday <- 1L
  end$isdst <- -1L
  breaks <- as.Date(seq(start, end, paste(step * 3L, 
                                          "months")))
  lb <- length(breaks)                   # Note this line
  if (maxx < breaks[lb - 1])             # If extra bin
    breaks <- breaks[-lb]                # Then remove extra bin
```

If we employ this same method and modify the section of code dealing with breaks="months":

```
if (valid == 3L) {
  start$mday <- 1L
  start$isdst <- -1L
  maxx <- max(x, na.rm = TRUE)     # Line added
  end <- as.POSIXlt(maxx)          # Line modified
  step <- if (length(by2) == 2L) 
    as.integer(by2[1L])
  else 1L
  end <- as.POSIXlt(end + (31 * step * 86400))
  end$mday <- 1L
  end$isdst <- -1L
  breaks <- as.Date(seq(start, end, breaks))
  lb <- length(breaks)             # Line added
  if (maxx < breaks[lb - 1])       # Line added
    breaks <- breaks[-lb]          # Line added
```

Storing the modified function in cut_Date, we get the following:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2021-1-1"),as.Date("2021-12-31"),by="day")
sextiles <- cut(dates,"2 months",labels=1:6)
# Error in cut.default(unclass(x), unclass(breaks), labels = labels, right = right,  : 
#   lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
sextiles <- cut_Date(dates,"2 months",labels=1:6)
table(sextiles)
# sextiles
#  1  2  3  4  5  6 
# 59 61 61 62 61 61
```

Bug fixed!

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to define "bins" for a number range such that all provided numbers are within one of the bins:

- find the minimum, find the maximum, and since `Date`-bins are generally `right=FALSE` meaning right-open, bump the maximum out a little; or
- find the minimum, and *don't* find the maximum, instead use `Inf` so that it always contains the maximum values.

`cut.Date` chose the first of the two. Further, instead of "bump out from the maximum by 1 day", it chose to "bump out by 'step'". This means that when you say `"2 months"`, it will ensure that the next bin "edge" is 2 months from the penultimate boundary.

Namely, if you look at the source for `cut.Date`:

```r
        start <- as.POSIXlt(min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
# ...
            end <- as.POSIXlt(max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
# and then if 'months', then
            end <- as.POSIXlt(end + (31 * step * 86400))
# and eventually
            breaks <- as.Date(seq(start, end, breaks))
```

So I'll `debug(cut.Date)` and take a look at `cut(dates, "2 months")`:

```r
start
# [1] "2021-01-01 UTC"
# debug: end <- as.POSIXlt(max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
# debug: step <- if (length(by2) == 2L) as.integer(by2[1L]) else 1L
end
# [1] "2021-12-31 UTC"
step
# [1] 2

# debug: as.integer(by2[1L])
# debug: end <- as.POSIXlt(end + (31 * step * 86400))
end
# [1] "2022-03-03 UTC"

# debug: end$mday <- 1L
# debug: end$isdst <- -1L
# debug: breaks <- as.Date(seq(start, end, breaks))
breaks
# [1] "2021-01-01" "2021-03-01" "2021-05-01" "2021-07-01" "2021-09-01" "2021-11-01" "2022-01-01"
# [8] "2022-03-01"
```

It then eventually does `breaks[-length(breaks)]`, which explains why we don't see *eight*. My guess is that there are corner cases (leap years, perhaps?) where the `31 * step * 86400` (or other `by`-units) do not always align perfectly, so they buffered it a little.

Long story short (too late), I suggest you use `labels=FALSE` instead.

```r
sextiles <- cut(dates, "2 months", labels = FALSE)
table(sextiles)
# sextiles
#  1  2  3  4  5  6 
# 59 61 61 62 61 61
```

If you want them to be integer-looking `factor`s (which are string levels with true integers underneath), then perhaps

```r
sextiles <- factor(sextiles)
head(sextiles)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: If that's an R bug, then congrats on finding it! It should be submitted to the R-devel mailing list.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans! Your elegant solution works great! In exploring your response, I found the bug in the code for cut.Date. It is simply missing a few lines of code that would test to see if the max date falls before the last bin, in which case it would remove that bin. If you look at the code for breaks="quarters", or valid==5L, the last line of code does just that for that case. It is necessary here as well for the same reason: because months have different numbers of days, creating inconsistent intervals.